# Why are these two expressions equal?

Tags: probability, algebra-precalculus

I am having a hard time figuring out why

$$2 \cdot \sum_{j = 1}^{\infty}\frac{j(j+1)}{2} \cdot \mathbb{P}\{N = j\} $$

is equal to the expression

$$2 \cdot \sum_{j = 1}^{\infty} j \cdot \mathbb{P}\{N \geq j\}.$$

Can someone make this more clear to me, please? I recognize the $j(j + 1)/2$ term to be the sum of integers; so, we can write

$$
\begin{align*}
2 \cdot \sum_{j = 1}^{\infty} \frac{j(j + 1)}{2} \cdot \mathbb{P}\{N = j\} \\
= 2 \cdot \sum_{j = 1}^{\infty}(1 + 2 + \cdots + j)\cdot \mathbb{P}\{N = j\}
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: **Hint**: Everything is non-negative here, so we can change the order of  summation.

Comment: What do you mean by $\mathbb{P}\{N = j\}$?